# flink global window aggregate checkpoint size keeps increasing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink sql query to count distinct user in the tumble window of 1 min, however checkpoint size of global window aggregate operator keeps increasing and memory as well.

[image: flink dag screenshot]

Comment: Which state backend are you using (RocksDB or heap)?

Comment: heapstatebackend, with rocksdb backend I'm not getting performance, even after parameters (block cache size, write buffer ) etc. tuning, not even sure what should be their values for production